# Using OpenStreetMap Transport layer as xyz in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

How can I use Openstreet Transport layer as baselayer in Openlayers?

```
var transport_layer =  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: '',
      url : 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}',

    })
  })
```

Comment: I am not sure. But I think it is hosted by https://www.thunderforest.com/. You need to sign up and get an apikey. When you have a key the url will be: `https://tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=<insert-your-apikey-here>`. More info here: https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/transport/

Comment: What about Humanitarian? It's free https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

Comment: The Humanitarian tile server also has a [usage policy](https://www.openstreetmap.fr/fonds-de-carte/).